# Drupal 6 - Get 5 newest nodes of a certain type

Tags: 6, nodes

I have a content type called "announcements". They each have a title and field for the announcement. I'd like to be able to, in my .module, get the last five announcements and print out their contents to the page. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module. It is awesome.